# Correct way to use universal quantifiers when specifying a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a set:

$X = \{p | p \in P \wedge \forall a(a \in A \wedge p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a))\}$

This reads (to me): the set containing all p, where p is an element of P, and for all a, a is an element of A and p is in F(a) and not in F'(a).

1) Does this read that for p to be in the set X, $p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a)$ for every occurrence of $a \in A$?

2) Would it be better as $X = \{p | p \in P \wedge \forall a(a \in A \rightarrow p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a))\}$ or does this mean that if $a \notin A$ then $p \in X$ because 0 -> anything = 1?

I want it to be the set (informally) of every element where the element is in F(a) and not in F'(a) for all a in A.

Hope that made sense. Thank you.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between what's stated and your interpretation: the original statement says $A$ contains EVERYTHING and your interpretation does not. I would say the original statement is kind of ill-defined and yours actually convey a clearer meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2) Would it be better as $X = \{p | p \in P \wedge \forall a(a \in A \rightarrow p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a))\}$

Yes, you definitely want that formulation.

In standard set theory a formula of the shape
$$ \forall a(a\in A\land \cdots) $$
is *always false*, because it can only be true if $A$ is such that *anything in the world* you can think of calling $a$ will be an element of it. And there is no such $A$ in standard set theory. So there will always be at least one $a$ that makes the $a\in A$ part false, and that itself dooms the entire $\forall$ -- it doesn't even matter what the other conjunct is.

> or does this mean that if $a \notin A$ then $p \in X$ because 0 -> anything = 1?

No -- the way the $\forall$ quantifier work is that your
$$ \forall a(a \in A \rightarrow p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a))$$
is true if and only if *every* $a$ somehow makes the formula in parentheses true. Thus for an $a$ that is not in $A$ you *want* that formula to be true -- this is how you ensure that those $a$ don't really contribute to the truth value of the $\forall$. When you have a $\forall$, a choice that makes the inner formula true is a "don't care" choice -- what you're interesting is whether there are any *counterexamples* or not.

---

As a matter of notation, you would usually write
$$X = \{p \in P \mid \forall a \in A:\,(p \in F(a) \wedge p \notin F'(a))\}$$
which expands to your formulation 2. In particular the *bounded quantifier* $\forall a\in A$ conventionally abbreviates the $\to$ form.

On the other hand $\exists a\in A:\;(\cdots)$ would abbreviate $\exists a(a\in A\land \cdots)$ because for an $\exists$ it is *false* that is the "don't care" value, and therefore $\land$ that encodes "ignore $a$s that don't satisfy this".

Comment: Great cheers mate, just more on the "When you have a ∀, a choice that makes the inner formula true is a "don't care" choice", could you elaborate on that a bit? Or do you have anywhere to point me to which goes into more detail about that?

Comment: @B.KLewis: You can think of $\forall$ as an infinite conjunction. The finite equivalent is that you can think of $P\land Q\land R$ as the same as $P\land Q\land R\land S\land T\land U$, provided you know that $S, T, U$ are all true. (In this analogy $S, T, U$ correspond to instances of the inner formula where $a$ has been chosen as something not in $A$).

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what you want to create, have you considered the following?

$$P\cap\bigcap_{a\in A}F(a)\setminus F'(a)$$

This equates to your number 2.